# When I deploy my app to Azure and save a timespan to my db I think it's in UTC

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

When I deploy my `Blazor` app to Azure and save a `TimeSpan` to my db I think it's in UTC? What's the typical pattern of saving `DateTime` stuff in Azure? This is a tiny we app, is it ok to save to database in my local time, if so how?

```
<InputText type="time" class="form-control form-control-sm" @bind-Value="Model.TimeIn" />
<InputText type="time" class="form-control form-control-sm" @bind-Value="Model.TimeOut" />
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me to add my local time to my SQL Database.
I have created a default sample Blazor app and added a `Add Time` page.

**#My Directory**

```
BlazorApp1/
│
├── models/
│ ├── Model.cs
|
├── Data/
│ ├── Adddbcontext.cs
│ ├── ...
│ 
├── Pages/
│ ├── Index.razor
│ ├── Counter.razor
│ ├── FetchData.razor
│ └── AddTime.razor
| ├── ...
│
├── Shared/
│ ├── MainLayout.razor
│ ├── NavMenu.razor
│ └── ...
│
├── App.razor
├── Program.cs
└── ...
```

**`adddbcontext.cs`**

```cs
using BlazorApp1.models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BlazorApp1.Data
{
    public class Adddbcontext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration Config;
        public Adddbcontext(IConfiguration configuration) 
        { 
            Config = configuration; 
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Config.GetConnectionString("Dbconnectionstring"));
            
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
        }

        public DbSet<Model> Time {  get; set; }
    }
}
```

**`Model.cs`**

```cs
namespace BlazorApp1.models
{
    public class Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Timein { get; set; }
        public string TimeOut { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**`AddTime.razor`**

```r
@page "/addtime"
@using BlazorApp1.models;
@inject Data.Adddbcontext Dbcontext;

<PageTitle>AddTime</PageTitle>
<h3>savetime</h3>
<EditForm Model="@newtime" OnValidSubmit="test">
    <InputText type="time" class="form-control form-control-sm" @bind-Value="newtime.Timein"/>
    <InputText type="time" class="form-control form-control-sm" @bind-Value="newtime.TimeOut" />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    @if(save)
    {
        <p>Time is saved</p>
    }
</EditForm>

@code {
    public Model newtime = new Model();
    public bool save = false;
    private async Task test()
    {
        try
        {
            Dbcontext.Time.Add(newtime);
            await Dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
            save = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Added this in the script to `NavMenu.razor` existing code to get `Add Time` menu.

```
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="addtime">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Time
            </NavLink>
        </div>
```

#**`OUTPUT`:**

Local Time is visible in the form.
[image]

[image]

**Time is saved in 24hr Format in SQL Database**

[image]